# AWS Private API and Cognito

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, oauth, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

We are developing an API for a client. Our standard has been to use Cognito as our auth mechanism (client credential flow). During development we learned that the client can only communicate privately so we have deployed the API in a VPC. Upon deployment, the client has indicated that they cannot reach Cognito to obtain a token because they can only communicate privately and cannot reach the public internet. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to allow the client to obtain a token from Cognito via the private VPC?

We have the API deployed as a private API using Cognito to verify a token that they retrieve from Congito. The quickest solution I can think of is to back off of Cognito and develop a custom authorizer using basic authentication isntead of Cognito authorizer.

Comment: Have you see this?
https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-patterns/tree/main/cognito-restapi-vpclink

Comment: So the issue seems to be that the client can not obtain a cognito token on the public internet (everything has to be done via the VPC). So getting the token from Cognito at https://<domain>.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token is a problem for them. We need to figure out a way for them to obtain a token from cognito via the same VPC where the API is deployed. This solution seems to be a way to create a private API in front of a non-private API but doesn't really address the Cognito piece unless I am completely misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when an application defined in VPC need to connect with other services of AWS/internet it happens through VPC endpoint but since it is not available yet for Cognito, you can configure a NAT gateway to your private subnet and then it will be able to communicate with internet without needing the clients to access internet directly. And since AWS is managing the NAT gateway, you can trust it to be secure.